# System restarts after entering bios setup

Tags: boot, bios

When I start my system, it shows the initial screen with dell logo, then shows the screen with options to choose The operating system (although I Have only windows 10 installed) for a brief second, and then restarts.
If i press any key during that options screen, it lets me choose the option of windows and it boots normally.
Other scenario: when I try to go to bios setup, by pressing f2 key continuously on boot screen, it enters the boot setup with blue screen (i can see the options) for a brief second and then restarts.
I don’t understand what has gone wrong here.
I must tell you that i even opened the laptop completely and removed the cmos battery to try to rest the bios. But I think reset Isn’t  Working as the time on my system does not reset after that.

What else can i try? Has my bios chip corrupted? Or its just a temporary thing?

Comment: If the BIOS Reset went wrong, about the only remedy I know which might possibly work is to install the current or newer BIOS from Dell for your specific model.

Comment: I am trying to install the latest bios that is A11 but when installing, it gives error saying cannot install same bios version. I wont be able to install from bootable drive because the same thing happens on boot device selection, it shows for a split second and then restarts.

Comment: That is not good news. You may need a new motherboard or (only possibly) a computer store that can replace the BIOS chip.

Comment: Can you access BIOS By inserting the windows 10 installation media, clicking Repair your computer then clicking UEFI firmware settings?